# React map() data not displaying

Tags: reactjs

The data does not appear in the table in the view. Importing data from db was confirmed with the console.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09l2u.png)

If it is simply used as list.map(), an error saying that it is not a function occurs. So list && list.length > 0 ? I am using list.map((e).
Or do I have to modify the const [list, setList] = useState code part?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

export default function Community() {

    const [list, setList] = useState([{
        inputData: {
            post_id: '',
            title: '',
            writer: ''
        },
    }]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/post/community').then((res) => {
            console.log("성공");
            console.log(res.data);
            setList(res.data);
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Box>
                <Button sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} href="/newpost">게시글 등록</Button>
            </Box>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table aria-label="simple table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Post_id</TableCell>
                            <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Title</TableCell>
                            <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} align="right">Writer</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    {list && list.length > 0 ? list.map((e) => {
                        return (
                            <TableBody>
                                <TableRow key={e.post_id}>
                                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{e.post_id}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">{e.title}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">{e.writer}</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableBody>
                        )
                    }) : ""}
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </div>
    );

}
```

Comment: According to the image, `res.data` isn't an array.  It's an *object*.  And there's no `.length` or `.map` on an object.  (You should also be getting a warning about that in the browser console, but since we're only looking at an image we can't scroll down to observe that.)  That object has a *property* called `results` which is an array.  Perhaps that's what you meant to set the state to?  `setList(res.data.results);` ?  Which would really just make this kind of a typo, just a mistake in interpreting your own data structure.

Comment: @David if it were not an array, this check `list && list.length > 0 ?` should prevent the execution of `list.map()` since list.length would be `undefined` hence he would not receive the `map is not a function` error. Probably he's missing some important info, but should definitely attach the result of a console.log(list) placed just before the return statement, and check what it displays before and after the fetch call.

Comment: inputData remove for this key & one object only

Answer (score 1):

Your first state is set up wrong which is then causing the map not to update the state data. It will only mutate not update.

Change

```
    const [list, setList] = useState([{
        inputData: {
            post_id: '',
            title: '',
            writer: ''
        },
    }]);
```

To this

```
    const [list, setList] = useState([])
```